# 2D Elastic Collisions - 'Sticking' Behaviour?

Tags: java, physics, sfml

I'm using this method to handle elastic collisions (using [this](http://www.vobarian.com/collisions/2dcollisions2.pdf) as a source):

```
public static void handleElasticCollisions(Entity a, Entity b) {
    // make a few variables to make equations easier to read
    Vector2f aPos = a.getPos();
    Vector2f bPos = b.getPos();

    Vector2f aV = a.getVelocity();
    Vector2f bV = b.getVelocity();

    float aMass = a.getSize();
    float bMass = b.getSize();

    // find unit normal vector
    Vector2f uN = normalize(Vector2f.sub(bPos, aPos));

    // find unit tanget vector
    Vector2f uT = new Vector2f(-uN.y, uN.x);

    // get normal and tangential components of both velocity vectors 
    // before the collision
    float aVn = dot(uN, aV);
    float aVt = dot(uT, aV);

    float bVn = dot(uN, bV);
    float bVt = dot(uT, bV);

    // get normal and tangential components of both velocity vectors 
    // after the collision
    float aVN = (aVn*(aMass - bMass) + 2*bMass*bVn)/(aMass + bMass);
    float aVT = aVt;

    float bVN = (bVn*(bMass - aMass) + 2*aMass*aVn)/(aMass + bMass);
    float bVT = bVt;

    // convert normal and tangential components into vectors
    Vector2f avn = Vector2f.mul(uN, aVN);
    Vector2f avt = Vector2f.mul(uT, aVT);

    Vector2f bvn = Vector2f.mul(uN, bVN);
    Vector2f bvt = Vector2f.mul(uT, bVT);

    a.setVelocity(Vector2f.add(avn, avt));
    b.setVelocity(Vector2f.add(bvn, bvt));
}
```

However, sometimes, entities go inside one another / stick to one another instead of bouncing away from each other. 
Here's my update method, with only relevant code:

```
public void show() {

    // set delta time
    float currentTime = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    float dt = currentTime - lastTime;


    // update entities and check for removal
    for (Entity e : entities) {
        e.update(dt);
    }

    // draw entities
    for (Entity e : entities) {
        e.draw();
    }


    Window.getWindow().draw(pointerSprite);
    Window.getWindow().display();

    lastTime = currentTime;

}
```

And in `update` of my colliding entities, I check this:

```
public boolean intersectsWithAsteroid() {
    for (Entity e : GameScreen.getEntities()) {
        if (e instanceof AsteroidEntity &&
                asteroidSprite.getGlobalBounds().intersection(e.getBounds()) != null &&
                !this.equals(e)) {
            collidingAsteroid = (AsteroidEntity)e;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void handleAsteroidIntersection() {
    CMath.handleElasticCollisions(this, collidingAsteroid);
}
```

[Here](http://jsfml.org/javadoc/org/jsfml/graphics/FloatRect.html#intersection(org.jsfml.graphics.FloatRect)) is the doc for `intersection`.

I don't understand why this occurs, can someone tell me how I'm implementing this algorithm wrong?

Comment: It's tremendously hard to figure out an answer here only based on the code snippets. An http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might help, but even then, one might have to invest some time for "debugging" - particularly when you say that they "*sometimes*" get stuck, it seems to be hard to specify the exact conditions of when this happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally fixed it, by adding these 3 lines of code to my response function:

```
    Vector2f rv = Vector2f.sub(bV, aV);
    Vector2f norm = Vector2f.sub(bPos, aPos);
    float velAlongNormal = CMath.dot(rv, norm);

    // Do not resolve if velocities are separating
    if(velAlongNormal > 0) {
        return;
    }
```

If the velocities of the objects were not directly colliding, then there shouldn't be a collision response. This solves all of the problems.